# Parse 1.8.3 ATS support not working

Tags: ios, parse-platform, app-transport-security

I'm using the latest version of Parse. 
I read their [downloads and changelog](https://parse.com/docs/downloads) notes and they state that they fully support [app-transport-security](/questions/tagged/app-transport-security) now. And according to their blog their were supposed to update their certificates on 11 Aug. However, when launching my app in iOS9, with the latest framework, I still get http cleartext errors. This is the only framework I use. I even tried adding an exception key for `api.parse.com` with no results